# Error connecting to NX server

Tags: nx

When trying to connect to NX server with a **NX CLient for Linux** (installed from `nxclient_3.5.0-7_amd64.deb`) I get the following error.

```
NX> 203 NXSSH running with pid: 8009
NX> 285 Enabling check on switch command
NX> 285 Enabling skip of SSH config files
NX> 285 Setting the preferred NX options
NX> 200 Connected to address: nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn on port: 22
NX> 202 Authenticating user: nx
NX> 208 Using auth method: publickey
Received disconnect from nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn: 2: Too many authentication failures for nx
```

However when I am trying to use NX plugin for **Remmina remote desktop client** (from `remmina-plugin-nx`) I get the following *different* error:

```
NX> 536 ERROR: Reached the maximum number of allowed users on this server.
```

The Remmina diagnostic log states that it is NXSERVER - Version 3.5.0-11 - LFE. Is it a problem on my (client) side, or on server side?

Comment: Knowing as much as nothing about NX, have you tried to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=NX+536+ERROR) that error?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I have hit the limit of **NX Free Edition** of NoMachine NX Server.  According to [NoMachine NX - Products Page](http://www.nomachine.com/features.php) the free edition of NX server is limited to maximum 2 concurrent connections and ***maximum 2 users***.

The [NX Licensing](http://www.nomachine.com/ar/view.php?ar_id=AR05F00510) article does not explain how those 2 users are calculated, and it is only implied that it is automatically two users which logged in / used NX server first.

The [nomachine sessions (nxserver)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=796207) thread on Ubuntu Forums says that server session info is stored at `/usr/NX/var/db`.  After examining those files it turns out that name of logged user is stored in session-info files there.

```
$ sudo grep -hR userName /usr/NX/var/db/* | sort | uniq
```

shows exactly two `userName`s.

---

I don't know why official NX Client for Linux has shown

> ```
> Too many authentication failures for nx
> ```

as error, and it took using NX plugin for Remmina to get

> ```
> NX> 536 ERROR: Reached the maximum number of allowed users on this server.
> ```

---

#### Postscript:

I turned to using [X2Go](http://www.x2go.org/) which doesn't have those limitations, is quite easy to install on Ubuntu (just add PPA), uses NX 3.x, though it is compatible only with itself.